# Frame target="_top"

Tags: html, iframe

Имеется HTML страничка с фреймом. Но на сайте, который грузится во фрейме имеются значения target="_top". 
target="_top" - Отменяет все фреймы и загружает страницу в полном окне браузера.
Можно ли как-то обойти это? 
А то при нажатии из фрейма на некоторые ссылки, переходит на сайт оригинал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратитесь к `frame.document` и там через `DOM` подредактируйте атрибут `target` каждой ссылки